There are 0 images belonging to 0 classes and I'm stuck
I'm trying to have the program run through the images in my google drive with google Colab, but it keeps giving an error at model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10, validation_data=test_generator)
I tried resizing the batch to 10 and resizing all of my images to 100 and I thought it would work, but it still gives me
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.

I put my training and testing images into two separate folder called "training_data" and "testing_data".
!pip install tensorflow
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB0
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score

#uploads the image
def load_image(image_location):
    # Load the image using OpenCV
    image = cv2.imread(image_location)

   #checks if image is uploaded or not
    if image is None:
        print("Error: image not found from", image_location)
        return None

    resized_image= cv2.resize(image, (100, 100))
    image_array = img_to_array(resized_image)

    image_array /= 255.0

    return image_array


example_image_location = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Machine Learning Folder/training_data/LightGreen_Crayon_Testing.jpg'

# Load and preprocess the example image
example_image = load_image(example_image_location)


if example_image is not None:

    # collecting/processing data
  train_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Machine Learning Folder/training_data'
  test_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Machine Learning Folder/testing_data'

  train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
  test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

  train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size=(100, 100), batch_size=10, class_mode='binary')

  test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir, target_size=(100, 100), batch_size=10, class_mode='binary')

    # model building
  base_model = EfficientNetB0(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
  x = base_model.output
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
  predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
  model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

  for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10, validation_data=test_generator)


Are the images formatted as ImageDataGenerator expects? That would be per-class folders with images inside. My guess is that you do not have that.

I never knew that images had to be formatted a specific way. Is there a certain way I should organize them or anything of that sort?

@zaelyn First of all ImageDataGenerator is deprecated. Now the way flow_from_directory works is by scanning the directory given for its sub-directories. The sub-directories are the names of the classes. you set the class_mode to binary, therefore it is looking to find images in sub dir 0 and sub dir 1. When you fit your train_generator and there are no 0 and 1 classes with images to learn which image belongs to which class then returns an error.
